# What is the use of track-by or key in v-for in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am new to the world of javascript and javascript-frameworks. What is the practical use of `track-by` or `key` in `v-for` in Vue JS?

I read the documentation, but did not really understand its use.

Comment: It's `key` in Vue. `track-by` is used in the documentation as an example from Angular. What particularly don't you understand?

Comment: @BertEvansI didn't understand the practical use of key. I think it was `track-by` in `Vue 1` and has been renamed to `key` in `Vue 2`. Why and where would I use it??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally I would recommend you use a `key` every single time that you are using `v-for`. The main reason for this is because Vue, for performance reasons, tries to be smart and and re-use existing components when it re-renders. This can cause you to run into problems, especially with components, because components have an internal state. If the component is not paying attention to changes in it's properties then it will render with it's previous internal state and it will appear as if the displayed information was not updated properly.

[Here is a prime example](https://jsfiddle.net/p58oc4dy/6/) from [a question I answered a few weeks ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43765209/38065). The fiddle shows iteration over a component without using a key.

```
<li v-for="item in items">
  <test-component :prop1="item"></test-component>
</li>
```

Notice when you click the **change data** button that the property values (the first list) change, but the internal state of the component (the second list) does not change. This would typically mean you would not see an update or would see something that did not appear to update in the Vue.

By adding a key to the components, however, you are telling Vue that each component has a specific ID that and Vue will only re-use that component if it has the same ID. This prevents a lot of odd behavior that typically shows up. [Here is that same fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/p58oc4dy/7/).

```
<li v-for="item in items" :key="item">
  <test-component :prop1="item"></test-component>
</li>
```

*Now* when you click the **change data** button you will notice that the internal state always matches the property.

This is literally [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44035837/38065) of the [most](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42707622/38065) common [fixes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43214344/38065) to [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43069570/38065) that pop up here on StackOverflow. Keys are not just useful for list rendering. Generally if you see something funny going on in Vue where a something does not appear to be updating the way you expect, using a key will fix the issue.

Here are a few relevant bits of information about key from the documentation.

- Using key with [lists](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key).
- Key is mandatory when iterating [components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Components-and-v-for).
- API documentation for [key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key).

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I have a question abut who Vue handle this situation. I understood the default behavior is track-by index, so when we click on sort data for example Vue will see the list still have 3 list items and reuse them, but if it is reusing it why the prop value which is again something related to component gets updated but not the data?

Comment: Any idea what is the scope of this key? For example, if there are two v-for loops one inside the other and a third one outside, should all these keys be unique at the global level, or is it enough to have them unique w.r.to their parent?

Comment: @GopalakrishnaPalem The scope of the key is the current component, so unique inside the component is fine.